# nested const JSX

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I think this is a weird question but i have a variable in React native  like this :

```
const phrases = {
Default: {
    title: "Fetching the Weather",
    subtitle: "Be patient, you're witnessing a miricle",
    highlight: "Fetching",
    color: "#636363",
    background: "#9C9C9C",
},
Clear: {
    title: "It's Amazing Balls",
    subtitle: "Rock that shit!",
    highlight: "Amazing",
    color: "#E32500",
    background: "#FFD017",
},
Rain: {
    title: "Rain rain please go away",
    subtitle: "Stay inside and code all day",
    highlight: "away",
    color: "#004A96",
    background: "#2F343A",
},
Thunderstorm: {
    title: "Thunder Strike",
    subtitle: "Unplug those devices",
    highlight: "Thunder",
    color: "#FBFF46",
    background: "#020202",
},
Clouds: {
    title: "Cloud storage limit reached",
    subtitle: "error: 5000 - cirrocumulus",
    highlight: "limit",
    color: "#0044FF",
    background: "#939393",
},
Snow: {
    title: "Brain Freeze",
    subtitle: "You're not supposed to eat it",
    highlight: "Brain",
    color: "#021D4C",
    background: "#15A678",
},
Drizzle: {
    title: "Meh... don't even ask",
    subtitle: "What did I just say?",
    highlight: "don't",
    color: "#B3F6E4",
    background: "#1FBB68",
},
Mist: {
    title: "Mist title",
    subtitle: "Mist sub",
    highlight: "Mist",
    color: "#B3F6E4",
    background: "#1FBB68",
},
```

}

now when i am trying to access Title like this :

```
 phrases[this.state.weather].title
```

I get this error :

undefined is not an object (evaluating'phrases[this.state.weather].title')

any one can help with this ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refrain from using language like that, even as examples (unless you're writing a rude language filter, of course).

Comment: `console.log(this.state.weather)` might be a good place to start

Comment: @Glorfindel my bad !!! I copy pasted the variable without checking, :/

Comment: @ted I did that, it is working fine, this.state.weather, is getting updated from my fetch

Comment: @FaroukLakhdhar does `this.state.weather` have a default that is not `undefined`? And in all cases, is it a `String`?

Comment: @Ted i did assign to it three dot: weather: '...', so when go through the const variable there is a ... value in it, and it is of type string

Comment: @FaroukLakhdhar there's your problem. The default for `this.state.weather` should be `'Default'` according top the limited code you have posted. `phrases['...']` is clearly always going to be `undefined`, based on your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Code like this `phrases['Clear'].title` works well. So, the only reason why your code `phrases[this.state.weather].title` doesn't work - your `this.state.weather` is `undefined`

Comment: so in my state.weather initial phase was '...', i just changed to Default and it is working. thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the `given weather` is a valid `weather` for `phrases`

```js
const phrases = {
  Default: {
    title: "Fetching the Fucking Weather",
    subtitle: "Be patient, you're witnessing a miricle",
    highlight: "Fucking",
    color: "#636363",
    background: "#9C9C9C",
  },
  Clear: {
    title: "It's Fucking Amaze Balls",
    subtitle: "Rock that shit!",
    highlight: "Fucking",
    color: "#E32500",
    background: "#FFD017",
  },
  Rain: {
    title: "Rain rain please go away",
    subtitle: "Stay inside and code all day",
    highlight: "away",
    color: "#004A96",
    background: "#2F343A",
  },
  Thunderstorm: {
    title: "Fucking Thunder Strike",
    subtitle: "Unplug those devices",
    highlight: "Thunder",
    color: "#FBFF46",
    background: "#020202",
  },
  Clouds: {
    title: "Cloud storage limit reached",
    subtitle: "error: 5000 - cirrocumulus",
    highlight: "limit",
    color: "#0044FF",
    background: "#939393",
  },
  Snow: {
    title: "Brain Fucking Freeze",
    subtitle: "You're not supposed to eat it",
    highlight: "Fucking",
    color: "#021D4C",
    background: "#15A678",
  },
  Drizzle: {
    title: "Meh... don't even ask",
    subtitle: "What did I just say?",
    highlight: "don't",
    color: "#B3F6E4",
    background: "#1FBB68",
  },
  Mist: {
    title: "Mist title",
    subtitle: "Mist sub",
    highlight: "Mist",
    color: "#B3F6E4",
    background: "#1FBB68",
  },
};

function phraseExists(name) {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(phrases, name);
}

function getDefaultPhrase() {
  return phrases.Default;
}

function getPhrase(name) {
  console.log(`Does "${name}" exist?`, phraseExists(name));

  return phraseExists(name) ? phrases[name] : null;
}

function getPhraseOrDefault(name) {
  return getPhrase(name) || getDefaultPhrase();
}


getPhrase('Foo'); // false
getPhrase('Mist'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that your component's this.state.weather has value undefined or something else unexpected. This kind of things should always be splitted in production code, so I recommend you to first get the object from phrases:

```
let phraseObj = this.state.weather ? phrases[this.state.weather] : undefined;
```

Then continue by checking if the value exists:

```
let result = phraseObj && phraseObj.title || 'No weather title found';
```

Yeah... so I guess there is something else not working that is not shown in the code shared here. I hope you find the real issue soon. :)

Comment: thank for your approach, more simple then throwing console.log everywhere, but i did define a couple of states and weather had three dots as an initial state, so upon calling, it was not recognised when go through the const